# Is it possible to speed-up background / text / border formatting?

Tags: excel, vba

**PLEASE SEE AHMED AU'S ANSWER AT THE END - HIS SOLUTION IS FANTASTIC! AFTER MY OLD CODE, I HAVE MY LATEST VERSION. THE DIFFERENCE IN SPEED IS STAGGERING!**

**THE INITIAL QUESTION:**
I'm converting a series of Excel spreadsheets to a dark theme. To do so, I wrote a simple macro (see below) that replaces current colors (e.g. background, text color and border) with specific RGB colors. The code works well but it takes too long to convert a single spreadsheet. My workbooks are big financial models, with multiple spreadsheets each. I was expecting each individual spreadsheet (let's say 300 lines, 50 columns) to convert in a few seconds. It is taking 30 minutes per spreadsheet!

Important to note that automatic calculation is off (and I don't need to recalculate anything to run this macro anyways)

The code I'm using is below [**THIS IS THE OLD CODE - SEE NEW CODE BELOW**]:

```
Sub Dark_mode()

Dim iR, iG, iB, fR, fG, fB As Integer
Dim current_line, current_column As Integer
Dim c_c As Range

Dim OldStatusBar As Boolean, current_run, line_start, line_end, column_start, column_end As Integer

'Prevents screen refreshing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    OldStatusBar = Application.DisplayStatusBar
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

' SET HERE LINES AND COLUMNS TO TRANSFORM
line_start = 211
line_end = 223
column_start = 1
column_end = 160

For current_line = line_start To line_end

    DoEvents
    Application.StatusBar = ">>>>>>> FORMATING: " & Format((current_line - line_start) / (line_end - line_start), "0%") & " completed <<<<<<<"

    For current_column = column_start To column_end

        Set c_c = Cells(current_line, current_column)

        With c_c.Interior
          iR = .Color Mod 256
          iG = (.Color Mod 256 ^ 2) \ 256
          iB = .Color \ (256 ^ 2)
        End With


        With c_c.Font
          fR = .Color Mod 256
          fG = (.Color Mod 256 ^ 2) \ 256
          fB = .Color \ (256 ^ 2)
        End With

        'CORE BACKGROUND
        If iR = 255 And iG = 255 And iB = 255 Then c_c.Interior.Color = RGB(51, 51, 51) 'white TO background I
        If iR = 227 And iG = 227 And iB = 227 Then c_c.Interior.Color = RGB(41, 41, 41) 'light gray TO background II
        If iR = 192 And iG = 192 And iB = 192 Then c_c.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'dark gray TO backgroun III

        'CORE TOPIC
        If iR = 0 And iG = 0 And iB = 0 Then c_c.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 102, 0) 'black TO green

        ' Ad hoc grays converted to green
        If iR = 128 And iG = 128 And iB = 128 Then c_c.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 102, 0) 'gray TO green
        If iR = 217 And iG = 217 And iB = 217 Then c_c.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 102, 0) 'gray TO green

        'CORE INPUT
        If iR = 255 And iG = 255 And iB = 153 Then c_c.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 51, 153) 'yellow TO blue
        If iR = 255 And iG = 255 And iB = 0 Then c_c.Interior.Color = RGB(120, 25, 25) 'bright yellow TO red

        'CORE TEXT
        If fR = 0 And fG = 0 And fB = 0 Then c_c.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'black TO white
        If fR = 0 And fG = 0 And fB = 255 Then c_c.Font.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) 'blue TO green
        If fR = 0 And fG = 128 And fB = 0 Then c_c.Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240) 'green TO blue
        If fR = 128 And fG = 0 And fB = 128 Then c_c.Font.Color = RGB(255, 204, 0) 'magenta TO orange
        If fR = 0 And fG = 128 And fB = 128 Then c_c.Font.Color = RGB(0, 204, 152) 'light blue TO pale green


        'CORE BORDERS (bottom/top/right/left colors)
        If c_c.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle <> -4142 Then
            With c_c.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                .Color = RGB(255, 217, 102)
            End With
        End If

        If c_c.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle <> -4142 Then
            With c_c.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                .Color = RGB(255, 217, 102)
            End With
        End If

        If c_c.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle <> -4142 Then
            With c_c.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
                .Color = RGB(255, 217, 102)
            End With
        End If

        If c_c.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle <> -4142 Then
            With c_c.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
                .Color = RGB(255, 217, 102)
            End With
        End If

   Next current_column
Next current_line

'Enables screen refreshing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = OldStatusBar

End Sub
```

**THIS IS THE NEW CODE:**

```
Sub Dark_mode()
' worksheet and range variables
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
' loop variables
Dim line_start As Integer, line_end As Integer, column_start As Integer, column_end As Integer
Dim Rw As Long, Col As Long
'current cell colors (for interior, font and border)
Dim IntClr As Long, FntClr As Long, BrdL As Long, BrdR As Long, BrdT As Long, BrdB As Long
Dim LnCnt As Long, ColCnt As Long
Dim iR As Integer, iG As Integer, iB As Integer, fR As Integer, fG As Integer, fB As Integer
' [i]nterior color variables
Dim IcRng1 As Range, IcRng2 As Range, IcRng3 As Range, IcRng4 As Range, IcRng5 As Range, IcRng6 As Range
Dim IClr1 As Long, IClr2 As Long, IClr3 As Long, IClr4 As Long, IClr5 As Long, IClr6 As Long
'[f]ont color variables
Dim fcRng1 As Range, fcRng2 As Range, fcRng3 As Range, fcRng4 As Range, fcRng5 As Range, fcRng6 As Range, fcRng7 As Range, fcRng8 As Range
Dim fClr1 As Long, fClr2 As Long, fClr3 As Long, fClr4 As Long, fClr5 As Long, fClr6 As Long, fClr7 As Long, fClr8 As Long
'[brd] color variables
Dim BrdRngL As Range, BrdRngR As Range, BrdRngT As Range, BrdRngB As Range
Dim BrdClr As Long

' SET HERE LINES AND COLUMNS TO TRANSFORM
line_start = 1
line_end = 130
column_start = 1
column_end = 45


LnCnt = line_end - line_start + 1
ColCnt = column_end - column_start + 1

'SET COLOR PATERNS FOR INTERIOR, TEXT AND BORDER
'Interior colors
IClr1 = RGB(51, 51, 51) 'format TO Core I
IClr2 = RGB(41, 41, 41) 'format TO Core II
IClr3 = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'format TO Core III
IClr4 = RGB(36, 64, 98) 'format TO Input
IClr5 = RGB(99, 37, 35) 'format to Special
IClr6 = RGB(33, 89, 103) 'format to Topic
'Font colors
fClr1 = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'format TO white (Core text / formula)
fClr2 = RGB(102, 204, 255) 'format TO blue (Number only)
fClr3 = RGB(204, 255, 102) 'format TO light green (Estimated figure)
fClr4 = RGB(255, 153, 102) 'format TO dark orange (Formula + number)
fClr5 = RGB(255, 204, 0) 'format TO orange (Other spreadsheet)
fClr6 = RGB(0, 255, 0) 'format TO bright green (FDS formula)
fClr7 = RGB(0, 255, 0) 'format TO magenta (Needs work)
fClr8 = RGB(0, 255, 0) 'format TO grey (Dim light)
'Border color
BrdClr = RGB(255, 217, 102) 'all borders to same color (yellow)


Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set Rng = Ws.Range(Cells(line_start, column_start), Cells(line_end, column_end))
tm = Timer()
Debug.Print ">>>>> STARTING LOOPS @ " & Now()

For Rw = 1 To LnCnt
    For Col = 1 To ColCnt

    IntClr = Rng(Rw, Col).Interior.Color
          iR = IntClr Mod 256
          iG = (IntClr Mod 256 ^ 2) \ 256
          iB = IntClr \ (256 ^ 2)

    FntClr = Rng(Rw, Col).Cells.Font.Color
          fR = FntClr Mod 256
          fG = (FntClr Mod 256 ^ 2) \ 256
          fB = FntClr \ (256 ^ 2)

    BrdL = Rng(Rw, Col).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle
    BrdR = Rng(Rw, Col).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle
    BrdT = Rng(Rw, Col).Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle
    BrdB = Rng(Rw, Col).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle


        'CORE BACKGROUNDS
        If iR = 255 And iG = 255 And iB = 255 Then Set IcRng1 = SimpleUnion(IcRng1, Rng(Rw, Col)) 'white to "Core I"
        If iR = 227 And iG = 227 And iB = 227 Then Set IcRng2 = SimpleUnion(IcRng2, Rng(Rw, Col)) 'light gray to "Core II"
        If iR = 192 And iG = 192 And iB = 192 Then Set IcRng3 = SimpleUnion(IcRng3, Rng(Rw, Col)) 'dark gray to "Core III"
        'Ad hoc colors converted to Core I/II/III
        If iR = 242 And iG = 242 And iB = 242 Then Set IcRng2 = SimpleUnion(IcRng2, Rng(Rw, Col)) 'light blue to "Input"

        'CORE INPUT
        If iR = 255 And iG = 255 And iB = 153 Then Set IcRng4 = SimpleUnion(IcRng4, Rng(Rw, Col)) 'LIGHT yellow to "Input"
        'Ad hoc colors converted to Input
        If iR = 204 And iG = 255 And iB = 255 Then Set IcRng4 = SimpleUnion(IcRng4, Rng(Rw, Col)) 'light blue to "Input"

        'CORE SPECIAL
        If iR = 255 And iG = 255 And iB = 0 Then Set IcRng5 = SimpleUnion(IcRng5, Rng(Rw, Col)) 'bright yellow to "Special"

        'CORE TOPIC
        If iR = 0 And iG = 0 And iB = 0 Then Set IcRng6 = SimpleUnion(IcRng6, Rng(Rw, Col)) 'black to "Topic"
        ' Ad hoc colors converted to TOPIC
        If iR = 0 And iG = 0 And iB = 128 Then Set IcRng6 = SimpleUnion(IcRng6, Rng(Rw, Col)) 'dark blue to "Topic"
        If iR = 128 And iG = 128 And iB = 128 Then Set IcRng6 = SimpleUnion(IcRng6, Rng(Rw, Col)) 'dark gray to "Topic"
        If iR = 217 And iG = 217 And iB = 217 Then Set IcRng6 = SimpleUnion(IcRng6, Rng(Rw, Col)) 'light gray to "Topic"


        'CORE TEXT
        If fR = 0 And fG = 0 And fB = 0 Then Set fcRng1 = SimpleUnion(fcRng1, Rng(Rw, Col)) 'black to "Core text / formula"
        If fR = 0 And fG = 0 And fB = 255 Then Set fcRng2 = SimpleUnion(fcRng2, Rng(Rw, Col)) 'blue to "Number only"
        If fR = 0 And fG = 128 And fB = 128 Then Set fcRng3 = SimpleUnion(fcRng3, Rng(Rw, Col)) 'light blue to "Estimated figure"
        If fR = 128 And fG = 0 And fB = 128 Then Set fcRng5 = SimpleUnion(fcRng5, Rng(Rw, Col)) 'magenta to "Other Spreadsheet"
        If fR = 0 And fG = 128 And fB = 0 Then Set fcRng6 = SimpleUnion(fcRng6, Rng(Rw, Col)) 'green to "FDS formula"


        'CORE BORDERS (bottom/top/right/left colors)
        If BrdL <> -4142 Then Set BrdRngL = SimpleUnion(BrdRngL, Rng(Rw, Col))
        If BrdR <> -4142 Then Set BrdRngR = SimpleUnion(BrdRngR, Rng(Rw, Col))
        If BrdT <> -4142 Then Set BrdRngT = SimpleUnion(BrdRngT, Rng(Rw, Col))
        If BrdB <> -4142 Then Set BrdRngB = SimpleUnion(BrdRngB, Rng(Rw, Col))
   Next Col
Next Rw

Debug.Print "Calculations time (sec.): " & Timer() - tm

'Prevents screen refreshing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Replace cell colors
If Not IcRng1 Is Nothing Then IcRng1.Interior.Color = IClr1
If Not IcRng2 Is Nothing Then IcRng2.Interior.Color = IClr2
If Not IcRng3 Is Nothing Then IcRng3.Interior.Color = IClr3
If Not IcRng4 Is Nothing Then IcRng4.Interior.Color = IClr4
If Not IcRng5 Is Nothing Then IcRng5.Interior.Color = IClr5
If Not IcRng6 Is Nothing Then IcRng6.Interior.Color = IClr6
'Replace text colors
If Not fcRng1 Is Nothing Then fcRng1.Font.Color = fClr1
If Not fcRng2 Is Nothing Then fcRng2.Font.Color = fClr2
If Not fcRng3 Is Nothing Then fcRng3.Font.Color = fClr3
If Not fcRng4 Is Nothing Then fcRng4.Font.Color = fClr4
If Not fcRng5 Is Nothing Then fcRng5.Font.Color = fClr5
If Not fcRng6 Is Nothing Then fcRng6.Font.Color = fClr6
If Not fcRng7 Is Nothing Then fcRng7.Font.Color = fClr7
If Not fcRng8 Is Nothing Then fcRng8.Font.Color = fClr8
'Replace borders colors
If Not BrdRngL Is Nothing Then BrdRngL.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Color = BrdClr
If Not BrdRngR Is Nothing Then BrdRngR.Borders(xlEdgeRight).Color = BrdClr
If Not BrdRngT Is Nothing Then BrdRngT.Borders(xlEdgeTop).Color = BrdClr
If Not BrdRngB Is Nothing Then BrdRngB.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Color = BrdClr

Debug.Print "Total time (sec.): " & Timer - tm

'Enables screen refreshing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function SimpleUnion(Xrng As Range, Yrng As Range) As Range

If Xrng Is Nothing Then
    Set SimpleUnion = Yrng
Else
    Set SimpleUnion = Union(Xrng, Yrng)
End If

End Function


' Gets color for background/text on cell at (linha, coluna)
Sub Get_color()

Dim iR, iG, iB As Integer
Dim fR, fG, fB As Integer
Dim linha, current_column As Integer

linha = 21
coluna = 20

Debug.Print "--- --- --- --- INTERIOR AND FONT COLORS --- --- --- ---"

    With ActiveSheet.Cells(linha, coluna).Interior
      iR = .Color Mod 256
      iG = (.Color Mod 256 ^ 2) \ 256
      iB = .Color \ (256 ^ 2)
    End With
    Debug.Print "Interior: [" & iR & ", " & iG & ", " & iB & "]"

    With ActiveSheet.Cells(linha, coluna).Font
      fR = .Color Mod 256
      fG = (.Color Mod 256 ^ 2) \ 256
      fB = .Color \ (256 ^ 2)
    End With
    Debug.Print "Font: [" & fR & ", " & fG & ", " & fB & "]"

End Sub
```

Comment: could you just select the whole range of cells then apply the format changes? instead of one cell at a time?

Comment: I can't select ranges. Although the color formating is almost always the same on my spreadsheets, they are customized to the company I'm modeling - therefore there is no standard patterns in terms of where I will have specific formats.

Comment: @An_old_dude, you could update the status bar and call `DoEvents` less frequently i.e. instead updating the % for every row, maybe update it for every 5 or 10 rows -- or something like that. My understanding is that `DoEvents` will keep the application responsive, but it will also reduce your code's performance (especially if in a tight loop). Also, only `fB` is declared an integer in this line: `Dim iR, iG, iB, fR, fG, fB As Integer`. The rest of them are implicit `variant`. In VBA, you must specify/hint the type for each variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for the heads-up on the declared variables: I guess I have been declaring 'variant' variables of Excel macros for ages! Out of curiosity, I declared all my variables as Integer - didn't change the speed (but probably used less memory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tried with the code (with approach to Calculate and then write each format category in one shot) and found working in seconds

```
Sub Dark_mode()
tm = Timer
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim iR As Integer, iG As Integer, iB As Integer, fR As Integer, fG As Integer, fB As Integer
Dim Rw As Long, Col As Long
Dim Rng As Range

Dim IcRng1 As Range, IcRng2 As Range, IcRng3 As Range, IcRng4 As Range, IcRng5 As Range, IcRng6 As Range, IcRng7 As Range, IcRng8 As Range
Dim IClr1 As Long, IClr2 As Long, IClr3 As Long, IClr4 As Long, IClr5 As Long, IClr6 As Long, IClr7 As Long, IClr8 As Long
Dim fcRng1 As Range, fcRng2 As Range, fcRng3 As Range, fcRng4 As Range, fcRng5 As Range
Dim fClr1 As Long, fClr2 As Long, fClr3 As Long, fClr4 As Long, fClr5 As Long
Dim BrdRngL As Range, BrdRngR As Range, BrdRngT As Range, BrdRngB As Range
Dim BrdClr As Long

Dim OldStatusBar As Boolean, current_run, line_start, line_end, column_start, column_end As Integer
Dim IntClr As Long, FntClr As Long, BrdL As Long, BrdR As Long, BrdT As Long, BrdB As Long
Dim LnCnt As Long, ColCnt As Long

' SET HERE LINES AND COLUMNS TO TRANSFORM
line_start = 211
line_end = 223

column_start = 1
column_end = 160

LnCnt = line_end - line_start + 1
ColCnt = column_end - column_start + 1

BrdClr = RGB(255, 217, 102)
IClr1 = RGB(51, 51, 51) 'white TO background I
IClr2 = RGB(41, 41, 41) 'light gray TO background II
IClr3 = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'dark gray TO backgroun III
IClr4 = RGB(0, 102, 0) 'black TO green (May be combined with iclr5 & 6)
IClr5 = RGB(0, 102, 0) 'gray TO green (May be combined with iclr4)
IClr6 = RGB(0, 102, 0) 'gray TO green (May be combined with iclr4)
IClr7 = RGB(0, 51, 153) 'yellow TO blue
IClr8 = RGB(120, 25, 25) 'bright yellow TO red

fClr1 = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'black TO white
fClr2 = RGB(0, 255, 0) 'blue TO green
fClr3 = RGB(0, 176, 240) 'green TO blue
fClr4 = RGB(255, 204, 0) 'magenta TO orange
fClr5 = RGB(0, 204, 152) 'light blue TO pale green


Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set Rng = Ws.Range(Cells(line_start, column_start), Cells(line_end, column_end))

For Rw = 1 To LnCnt
    For Col = 1 To ColCnt

    IntClr = Rng(Rw, Col).Interior.Color
    FntClr = Rng(Rw, Col).Cells.Font.Color
    BrdL = Rng(Rw, Col).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle
    BrdR = Rng(Rw, Col).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle
    BrdT = Rng(Rw, Col).Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle
    BrdB = Rng(Rw, Col).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle

          iR = IntClr Mod 256
          iG = (IntClr Mod 256 ^ 2) \ 256
          iB = IntClr \ (256 ^ 2)

          fR = FntClr Mod 256
          fG = (FntClr Mod 256 ^ 2) \ 256
          fB = FntClr \ (256 ^ 2)


        'CORE BACKGROUND
        If iR = 255 And iG = 255 And iB = 255 Then Set IcRng1 = SimpleUnion(IcRng1, Rng(Rw, Col))
        If iR = 227 And iG = 227 And iB = 227 Then Set IcRng2 = SimpleUnion(IcRng2, Rng(Rw, Col))
        If iR = 192 And iG = 192 And iB = 192 Then Set IcRng3 = SimpleUnion(IcRng3, Rng(Rw, Col))
        'CORE TOPIC
        If iR = 0 And iG = 0 And iB = 0 Then Set IcRng4 = SimpleUnion(IcRng4, Rng(Rw, Col))
        ' Ad hoc grays converted to green
        If iR = 128 And iG = 128 And iB = 128 Then Set IcRng5 = SimpleUnion(IcRng5, Rng(Rw, Col))
        If iR = 217 And iG = 217 And iB = 217 Then Set IcRng6 = SimpleUnion(IcRng6, Rng(Rw, Col))
        'CORE INPUT
        If iR = 255 And iG = 255 And iB = 153 Then Set IcRng7 = SimpleUnion(IcRng7, Rng(Rw, Col))
        If iR = 255 And iG = 255 And iB = 0 Then Set IcRng8 = SimpleUnion(IcRng8, Rng(Rw, Col))


        'CORE TEXT
        If fR = 0 And fG = 0 And fB = 0 Then Set fcRng1 = SimpleUnion(fcRng1, Rng(Rw, Col))
        If fR = 0 And fG = 0 And fB = 255 Then Set fcRng2 = SimpleUnion(fcRng2, Rng(Rw, Col))
        If fR = 0 And fG = 128 And fB = 0 Then Set fcRng3 = SimpleUnion(fcRng3, Rng(Rw, Col))
        If fR = 128 And fG = 0 And fB = 128 Then Set fcRng4 = SimpleUnion(fcRng4, Rng(Rw, Col))
        If fR = 0 And fG = 128 And fB = 128 Then Set fcRng5 = SimpleUnion(fcRng5, Rng(Rw, Col))


        'CORE BORDERS (bottom/top/right/left colors)
        If BrdL <> -4142 Then Set BrdRngL = SimpleUnion(BrdRngL, Rng(Rw, Col))
        If BrdR <> -4142 Then Set BrdRngR = SimpleUnion(BrdRngR, Rng(Rw, Col))
        If BrdT <> -4142 Then Set BrdRngT = SimpleUnion(BrdRngT, Rng(Rw, Col))
        If BrdB <> -4142 Then Set BrdRngB = SimpleUnion(BrdRngB, Rng(Rw, Col))
   Next Col
Next Rw

Debug.Print "Calc Over " & Timer - tm
'Prevents screen refreshing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Not IcRng1 Is Nothing Then IcRng1.Interior.Color = IClr1
If Not IcRng2 Is Nothing Then IcRng2.Interior.Color = IClr2
If Not IcRng3 Is Nothing Then IcRng3.Interior.Color = IClr3
If Not IcRng4 Is Nothing Then IcRng4.Interior.Color = IClr4
If Not IcRng5 Is Nothing Then IcRng5.Interior.Color = IClr5
If Not IcRng6 Is Nothing Then IcRng6.Interior.Color = IClr6
If Not IcRng7 Is Nothing Then IcRng7.Interior.Color = IClr7
If Not IcRng8 Is Nothing Then IcRng8.Interior.Color = IClr8

If Not fcRng1 Is Nothing Then fcRng1.Font.Color = fClr1
If Not fcRng2 Is Nothing Then fcRng2.Font.Color = fClr2
If Not fcRng3 Is Nothing Then fcRng3.Font.Color = fClr3
If Not fcRng4 Is Nothing Then fcRng4.Font.Color = fClr4
If Not fcRng5 Is Nothing Then fcRng5.Font.Color = fClr5

'may be all 4 type of BrdRng combined to one
If Not BrdRngL Is Nothing Then BrdRngL.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Color = BrdClr
If Not BrdRngR Is Nothing Then BrdRngR.Borders(xlEdgeRight).Color = BrdClr
If Not BrdRngT Is Nothing Then BrdRngT.Borders(xlEdgeTop).Color = BrdClr
If Not BrdRngB Is Nothing Then BrdRngB.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Color = BrdClr

Debug.Print "Final " & Timer - tm


'Enables screen refreshing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Function SimpleUnion(Xrng As Range, Yrng As Range) As Range
If Xrng Is Nothing Then
Set SimpleUnion = Yrng
Else
Set SimpleUnion = Union(Xrng, Yrng)
End If
End Function
```

may be modified to your requirements. if found to achieve required speed with actual files involved may be looped for formatting multiple files and multiple ranges from a simple master file (containing the macro) with a list of File path,names, sheet and ranges.

Any further problems, clarification, feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your help. Your solution was fantastic: to first select all ranges that were matching each internal/font/border and only after apply the new settings, made a huge difference. Probably because I was selecting each cell and immediately re-formating each cell, the process was absurdly resource consuming for Excel. You transformed a macro that, on my bigger spreadsheets, was taking hours to run, in less than a minute process! I'm really impressed with your skills but even more impressed with your willingness to help!