# Adding new data series changes Excel 2016 chart format

Tags: excel

I'm adding a new series to a chart I have and Excel 2016 (Windows 10) keeps changing the format, automatically. I'm a very experienced user and don't recollect ever having this issue. Here is the chart before any changes:

[image: Original chart]

Here is what happens when I add another prices series (same dates as the share price on the chart but adjusted for dividends):

[image: Chart after adding a new price series]

I tried going to Options / Advanced / Charts and unselecting both "Properties follow chart data point for all new workbooks" and "Properties follow chart data point for current workbook" - didn't help.

If I open my Visual Basic Editor and click on "ThisWorkbook", the ChartDataPointTrack is indeed selected to "False".

So what am I missing here?

**Extra info #1:**

Given 'Terry W' question about data samples, to avoid dumping too much info here, I will describe what they are ( I don't think this is the issue, as there is nothing special on the data; all series are scatter-plots):

- the share prices are daily share prices for Coca-Cola [KO]. The original series was the regular share price anyone sees on a day-to-day basis, the series I added was the "Adjusted Price" (i.e., the historical share price adjusted for dividends).
- The historical dots in red/light-red are quarterly earnings (annualized) - so not a lot of data
- The dots in the future are just one per year - so very little data

**Extra info #2:**

I noticed that when adding a new series (done by [i] right-clicking on the chart, [ii] clicking on "Select Data..." and [iii] clicking on "Add") but limiting the number of days added, the formating holds! See the picture below: I added 2,000 days of data vs. the 5,500 days I have for the other price series.

[image: New series added with limited days]

I was able to go up to 4,000 days with no issues. As soon as I used "5000", it changed the format. By "used" I mean, changing the reference on the window below you see superimposed to the chart:

[image: New series with an error at 5000]

**Extra info #3:**

As you noticed, my charts are in a dark format. This is because I work long hours with spreadsheets and dark formats are much more gentle on my tired eyes (I have posted a macro I wrote to darken spreadsheets [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55543789/is-it-possible-to-speed-up-background-text-border-formatting)). When converting some charts to dark format, I could have used a macro like the one below. I'm not sure if that was the case for this specific chart, but decided to add the code anyways in case it helps someone to solve the mystery:

```
Dim s_name As String

For Each Shape In ActiveSheet.Shapes

    s_name = Shape.Name

    ' Format all charts to style #209
    If Shape.Type = msoChart Then
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(s_name).Activate
        ActiveChart.ClearToMatchStyle
        ActiveChart.ChartStyle = 209
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(s_name).ZOrder msoSendToBack
    End If
```

Comment: are you able to share a sample of the original data set and the new data set behind your chart, and explain how did you add the the new data to the chart? I not sure how to reproduce your problem to start with.

Comment: I have the same problem, when you add / remove data, the formatting is reset to defaults: colors, lines... "New" "improved" "features" from MS, to "justify" the money they charge. I confirm that in the past, the behavior was as you expect: you modify the data and all the formatting is preserved. I also use Excel 2016. I went the easy way and decided to leave all formatting to defaults, so I do not need to bother with this.

Comment: In images [#1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WGb1.png) and [#2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvqci.png), it appears that the right side of your charts has not changed (data-wise, though the markers display in #1 and not #2), and there is data for Green (RIM-EPS), though the green data on the left in #1 does not display and appears to begin displaying in #2.  Did you hide that data in #1?  My assumption is that the matching colors are related from left side and right side of the individual images.

Comment: @virolino: please vote the question up so more people might be alerted to this issue; also read my "extra info" above: maybe this is a silly bug on Excel 2016? How come I can add a few days of data, without changing the format, but not for the whole amount of days I want?

Comment: Not an identical solution, but have you see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1371224/excel-chart-formatting-lost-when-refresh-all-or-individual-right-click-on-data)?  They describe that it's an XML issue... that post is related to pivot tables/charts, but may be subject to the same basic issue.

Comment: Hopefully last question (sorry), have you tried saving your workbook as `.xlsb`?  My assumption is you're using `.xlsm`, which similar to the above comment where I linked another post.

Comment: @Cyril: thank you for your comments. I read the post with the issue with PivotTable but I couldn't make a connection with the issue I have. Saving as a .xlsb didn't solve the issue either, but it makes the opening/saving of my models much faster! Not sure why I haven't been using this format for the past decade!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a macro that would add series to the chart.  My issue turned out to be that I was setting the chart type to xlXYScatter before adding the new series. This was resetting the formats of series already on the chart to the default for that type, which is not what I wanted.  In my case, leaving the chart type and explicitly setting the new series' format in the macro fixed the problem.
While that was not happening with the original poster's situation, I has me wondering if crossing the data series threshold implicitly changed the chart type.